# Can ZCash be implemented as ERC-20 token or does it require another standard?

Tags: erc-20, tokens, bitcoin

Obviously, you can implement e.g. Bitcoin as an ERC-20 token, but ZCash seems to have a way more complicated interface. I wonder if there is a standard describing tokens dealing with anonymity.

Answer (score 0):

You can see that Zcash is implemented as an ERC20 token in Binance Smart Chain Mainnet here:

https://explorer.bitquery.io/bsc/token/0x1ba42e5193dfa8b03d15dd1b86a3113bbbef8eeb

Comment: I saw that but it didn't make direct sense, erc-20 requires that sender specifies who he's sending to and how much, but ZCash is supposed to hide that information.